# Passing context from fragment to an adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

How do I pass a context from a `fragment` to an adapter? I have tried **getActivity()** and **getContext()** inside a fragment but nothing worked.Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public class Men extends Fragment {

        RecyclerView my_recyclerView1;
        ArrayList<Tab_1_DataActivity> tab1;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            my_recyclerView1 = (RecyclerView) container.findViewById(R.id.tab1_recyclcer);
            my_recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            tab1 = new ArrayList<>();
            loadData();
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_1, container, false);
        }

        private void loadData() {
            String tab1_URL = "";
            StringRequest first_tab = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, tab1_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSON HERE...
                        MyAdapter my_recyclerView1Adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), tab1);
                        my_recyclerView1.setAdapter(my_recyclerView1Adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("MyExeption", "MineJSONException", e);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            MySingletonActivity.getmInstance(getActivity()).addtoRequest(first_tab);
        }
    }
```

Comment: pass `this` ....

Comment: but this is not allowed in fragment....

Comment: it is allowed ..... put your whole code here ....

Comment: pass  `getActivity()`

Comment: pass as @ArpitPrajapati says ....

Comment: What's the error? Perhaps you're just forgetting to put data in tab1...

Comment: Everytime app crashes. java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                     at com.example.powerclub.againjson.Men.onCreateView(Men.java:37)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)

Comment: And Men.java at line 37 is where you set your layoutmanager? In that case, it has nothing to do with the context and the adapter. It is that you cannot find a view by id. Btw it smells fishy that you are looking for the view in the /container/ rather than the view you inflate yourself.

Comment: Btw the id is mispelled, in case you didn't notice: R.id.tab1_recyclcer

Answer (score 2):

Declare the getContext() method and derive it from container.

```
public class Men extends Fragment {

RecyclerView my_recyclerView1;
ArrayList<Tab_1_DataActivity> tab1;
Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 context = container.getContext();
 //put the rest of your code and put context in place of getContext or getActivity
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code ....**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_1, container, false); // add line
    my_recyclerView1 = (RecyclerView) view .findViewById(R.id.tab1_recyclcer); // change line
    my_recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity())); // change line
    tab1 = new ArrayList<>();
    loadData();
    return view; // change line
}
```

**Change these lines also ...**

```
MenAdapter my_recyclerView1Adapter = new MenAdapter(getActivity(), tab1);//change line
                my_recyclerView1.setAdapter(my_recyclerView1Adapter);
```

Comment: use `getActivity().getContext(); or directly use `getActivity();``

Comment: Tried getActivity() but failed.

Comment: Post the logcats error with your adapter ..... whey failed using `getActivity()`;

Comment: It says no adapter attached.Skipping Layout.

Comment: will you post your adapter here ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List <Article> articles;
private int rowLayout;
private Context mContext;
WebView articleView;
private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
private static final int NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;



public ArticleAdapter(List<Article> list, int rowLayout, Context context)
{
     this.articles = list;
     this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
     this.mContext = context;
}}
```

passing context like this `private Context mContext;`

Comment: Can u specify an example?

Comment: Thankss for ur effort.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```
private RecyclerView my_recyclerView1;
private ArrayList<Tab_1_DataActivity> tab1;
private MenAdapter my_recyclerView1Adapter

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    my_recyclerView1 = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab1_recyclcer);
    my_recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager());
    tab1 = new ArrayList<>();
    loadData();
}

private void loadData() {
    StringRequest first_tab = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, tab1_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            // your implementation...


            // Use runOnUiThread to avoid cross threading
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MenAdapter my_recyclerView1Adapter = new MenAdapter(getActivity(), tab1);
                    my_recyclerView1.setAdapter(my_recyclerView1Adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        // Your code
    });

    MySingletonActivity.getmInstance(getActivity()).addtoRequest(first_tab);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    // you can cast this context to activity

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

Comment: Also override the `onAttach` (Called when a fragment is first attached to its activity) function.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a specific activity context in adapter?

You can use viewHolder context

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MenAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
 Picasso.with(holder.getContext()).load(tab1.get(position).getProd_img()).into(holder.imageTab1);
}
```

`